# How to subtract continuously from a number

Tags: python

Beginner python user here. I'm writing some code for a basic attack in an rpg, and it looks like this:

```py
import random
class attack:

    health = 300

    for i in range(1):
        if (random.uniform(0, 10)) <= int(8.2):
            health = health - 50
            print("Your attack hit.\n" + "The monster's health is at " + str(health))
        else:
            print("Your attack missed.\n" + "The monster's health is at " + str(health))
```

When the attack hits, this is what's printed:

```
Your attack hit.
The monster's health is at 250
```

I'm trying to continuously subtract from the heath until it goes down to zero. How do I write this so that 50 continuously subtracts from 300 whenever I run the program (instead of just staying at 250)?

Comment: to continue you have to use something bigger then only `range(1)` - ie. `range(5)` for 5 hits - or  `while True` for infinity loop and use `break` to exit it. OR `while health > 0:` instead of `for`-loop.

Comment: Or `while health > 0:` to keep attacking until you win.

Comment: Health should be a property of your monster object. In other words, you should have that implied in your monster class.

Comment: Your code would work equivalently without the `class attack:` line. You may want to remove from the example code, to prevent confusion.

Comment: What is the desired output of the fixed program?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `while` loop- it'll run until the condition's met (in this case, until health is 0):

```
while health > 0:
    if (random.uniform(0, 10)) <= int(8.2):
            health = health - 50
            print("Your attack hit.\n" + "The monster's health is at " + str(health))
        else:
            print("Your attack missed.\n" + "The monster's health is at " + str(health))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a while loop like

```
while health > 0:
    if (random.uniform(0, 10)) <= int(8.2):
        health = health - 50
        print("Your attack hit.\n" + "The monster's health is at " + str(health))
    else:
         print("Your attack missed.\n" + "The monster's health is at " + str(health))
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-while-statement

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is only executing once.

```
for i in range(1):
```

If you want it to run until `health` is `0`, you'll need a `while` loop:

```
while health > 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use a function, instead of a class, and you can use a while loop to keep on attacking into health is smaller then 0.

```
import random
def attack():
    health = 300
    while health > 0:
        if (random.uniform(0, 10)) <= int(8.2):
             health -= 50
             print("Your attack hit.\n" + "The monster's health is at " + str(health))
        else:
             print("Your attack missed.\n" + "The monster's health is at " + str(health))
attack()
```